# XCode, svn, ssh worked before Time Machine restore - now not so much

Tags: xcode, svn

OK, so not so much about programming as about svn, ssh and XCode..

My SSD died, so I popped in a hard drive and restored everything from Time Machine . Machine works well except for SVN. It can't find the repo.

Url is svn+ssh://andersprivat@localhost/Library/Subversion/Repository/WriteAssist

The repo seems to be there (at/Library/Subversion/Repository/WriteAssist). XCode asks for the password, but then fails.

When using svn from the cmdline I get this:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:Classes andersprivat$ svn commit -m "Test" PredictorSettingsModel.m 
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

Suggestions?

Comment: and what happens when you 'remove the -q option from ssh'?

Comment: I'd tell you if I knew where to go and do it :) Still trying to find out.

Comment: Well, it's obviously not ~/.subversion/config as changes here don't seem to be noticed at all.

Comment: I can't take credit for the answer, but use the first result when searching for `To better debug SSH connection problems`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ssh daemon is not enabled by default on a Mac, so when restoring a user to a fresh installation you need to enable it. SYstem settings -> Sharing, enable Remote login. You may want to restrict it to your personal user just in case.